# How can I change the dark color of (a vanilla) "Gnome" Shell-Theme into the white-ish default "Gnome Classic" Shell-theme color?

Tags: gnome, themes, gnome-classic

How can I change the dark color of a **default** (vanilla) "**Gnome**" **Session** **Shell-Theme** into the light (white-ish) **default** "**Gnome Classic**" **Shell-theme** color?

*It should be possible (at least, in my understanding) to do so without much effort, since I can already log in to a session (Gnome classic) that shows that theme version perfectly installed and working. Unluckily, I didn't find anything that can explain how to do that online...*

Here are my screenshots, in order to better understand what I mean:

- **MY VANILLA "GNOME SESSION" Shell Theme**
  https://ibb.co/GkMC8y0
- **MY VANILLA "GNOME-CLASSIC SESSION" Shell Theme**
  https://ibb.co/1fbC3t4

***(the latter - long story short - is the theme I want to apply to my regular "Gnome" session)***

I have "Gnome Tweaks" installed and "Shell Themes" extension activated (but the white theme simply won't show anywhere in order to be selected)

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. Sharing here if anybody's interested:

mkdir -p $HOME/.themes/light/gnome-shell

cd $HOME/.themes/light/gnome-shell

cp /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gnome-classic.css ./gnome-shell.css

Then Tweaks have to be opened and the “User themes” extension activated (if it wasn't before). Now we need to close Tweaks. Then we have to open it again and go to -> Appearance -> Shell, and change "Default" to "Light".

That works seamlessly.